# how to create customised silver app bar in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack

I want build a app in jetpack compose with customised app means a silver app with list. thanks in advance

jetpack compose silver app bar [check here for UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFbwv.png)

Comment: You should elaborate your requirements clearly. Like you can attach some samples of your app or any other app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check here

```
   @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TopAppBarWithScaffold() {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = { LargeTopAppBar(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior) }
    ) { padding ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        ) {
            items(50) {
                ListItem(
                    headlineContent = { Text(text = "Item $it") },
                    leadingContent = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Face,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `LargeTopAppBar` fun create

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LargeTopAppBarM3(
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior
) {
    LargeTopAppBar(
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "Silver App bar",
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { /* do something*/ }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Open Menu")
            }
        },
        actions = {

            IconButton(onClick = { /* do something*/ }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings, contentDescription = "Open Settings")
            }

        }
    )
}
```